# Uploading images Asynchronously to amazon S3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How do I upload images to S3 Asynchronously, I mean the client does not have to wait until all images are done uploading to take the user to the next page of the form.

I first upload the images to my server on a temp directory, via ajax, then when the user submit the form I take those same images and upload it to S3, this step from temp to S3 take a while.

Right now I have this logic in place and working:

```
//Upload img to S3
    AwsHelper.UploadImage(sourceFileSmall, targetFileSmall, photo.FileNameSmall, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWS_bucket_PropertyImg"]);

//delete the temp local img after upload
    System.IO.File.Delete(sourceFileSmall);

//I call this method several more times, one for each image size
```

But this takes a while because depending on the quantity it takes up to 1 minute.

I did try Wrapping this code inside a:

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { 
        AwsHelper.UploadImage(sourceFileSmall, targetFileSmall, photo.FileNameSmall,    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWS_bucket_PropertyImg"]);
        System.IO.File.Delete(sourceFileSmall);
        //I call this method several more times, one for each image size
    });
```

It does delays execute the code asynchronously and the user is taken to the next step of the form but for some reason it does not upload the files and I don't get any exceptions either.

Answer (score 1):

The [TransferUtility class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/TS3_Transfer_TransferUtility_NET4_5.html) can provide asynchronous uploads/downloads to Amazon S3.